# How to use npm audit with NPM workspaces?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-workspaces

For a project using the AWS CDK we are moving from lerna to NPM workspaces. Everything seems fine so far, except for running `npm audit` in the project root, which doesn't seem to take the workspace into account.

We are using the following folder structure:

```
.
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json
|-ts-config.json
|-lib
 |-index.ts
 |-lambdas
  |-workspace-a
   |-index.ts
   |-package.json
```

When adding a dependency with vulnerabilities to the project root's `package.json`, `npm audit` greets us with the report of those as usual.
When installing the same dependency in the `workspace-a package.json`, it ends up in the project's root `package-lock.json` section for the workspace, as expected, but goes unnoticed by `npm audit` and reports 0 vulnerabilities.

So far I have tried several ways of running `npm audit`; by adding `--workspaces=true`, `--workspace lib/lambdas/workspace-a` and `--package-lock-only`, but neither seem to work.

Is there something I'm failing to see to get `npm audit` to work for `workspace-a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing with sample projects on the same and different machines, the solution seems to lie in the registry set in the `.npmrc`. When commenting out the enterprise npm repository, the audits get picked up again.

Alternatively, running `npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` will work without changing the global config.

This only seems to be needed for audits on workspaces and nested dependencies, as the top-level dependencies on the root package level will be audited just fine either way.